# Which package is needed for \boldsymbol{}?

Tags: bold

I am using `\boldsymbol{}` and `\textit{}`, but they are not recognized. The document preamble is the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath, calc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometryit is}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}

For example, I'm using $\boldsymbol{x}_t$ and 
\textit{vector de estados} within a paragraph.

\end{document}
```

Which lines concern the font or the commands that are not working? What should I change?

Comment: You have an issue with `\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometryit is}`... that's completely irrelevant to your question, but it remains a problem.

Comment: It should be `\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}` since there's no package called `geometryit is`.

Comment: In answer to your question, `\textit` is available by default and `\boldsymbol` is supplied by [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) (even though `\bm` from [`bm`](//ctan.org/pkg/bm) is a suggested improvement/alternative).

Comment: But if I'm using `\usepackage{amsmath, calc}`, why is `\boldsymbol{}` not working? And if `\textit{}` is default, why is it not working either?

Comment: There's nothing that points to `\textit` being disable/unavailable based on your code snippet. So the problem must be somewhere else...

Comment: But should I change the font or something of the kind?

Comment: Nothing in your current code snippets points to being problematic (except for the `geometryit is` missing package).

Comment: For example, I'm using `$\boldsymbol{x}_t$` and `\textit{vector de estados}` within a paragraph. Is something wrong with that?

Comment: @AlfieGonzález: Nothing is wrong with that...

Comment: you need to fix your example so that people can run it and see the problem. the example needs to be complete from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: oh you are using `mathptmx` which does not have bold math fonts, so that explains `\boldsymbol`  (try newtxtext,newtxmath instead

Comment: you are using packages designed for pdftex (inputenc, mathptm) but then using fontspec which requires xetex or luatex. This is going to lead to errors. Are you using pdflatex (if so remove fontspec)  or xetex or luatex (in which case remove inputenc, and mathptmx)

Comment: That worked! I commented the lines with `inputenc` and `mathptmx` and the bold symbols and italics appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath, calc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

For example, I'm using $\boldsymbol{x}_t$ and \textit{vector de estados} within a paragraph.
\end{document}
```

`mathptmx` is very old and has no bold fonts, a better times clone is `newtxmath`

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath, calc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

For example, I'm using $\boldsymbol{x}_t$ and \textit{vector de estados} within a paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please use the package `bm` in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{bm}
```

And in document use

```
\bm{}
```

For examples, bold symbols with italic shape are

```
$\bm{\alpha}=\bm{t}$
```

compared with them, the normal symbols are

```
$\alpha=t$
```

The compiled PDF for them would be

[image]

By the way,

- in fact `\bm{}` won't change any shape of symbols but only increase
  the thickness of symbols.
- `bm` package can be used under every
  mathematical fonts, including `mathptmx` you used.

Comment: bm can really only make acceptable output if there is a bold font available (it can use poor man's bold, overprinting three copies of the symbol with slight offsets, but that's not recommended)

Comment: Another reason to stick to boldsymbol is that the command is avaiblable by default in Mathjax, which comes in handy e.g. when writing documentation with *Doxygen*.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle A quotation from your book the 'LaTeX companion' (2nd edition): "Although `amsmath` provides `\boldsymbol` and `\pmb`, the rules about about when to use which command, and many of the restrictions on when they work, can now be avoided: just load the `bm` package and use `\bm` to make any formula as bold and beautiful as the available fonts allow''. ;)